# ArrayList C# Contains method query

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<myClass>` list. It contains a 10 objects of type `MyClass`.

```
class MyClass
{
  string name;
  int age;
}
```

If I want to find all items in list where `age = 10`, can I use the `Contains` method?
If yes how can I do this without using iteration?

Comment: Your question talks about ObservableCollection, but your title talks about ArrayList. Please edit to be consistent.

Answer (score 6):

```
var age10 = list.Where(i => i.age == 10);
```

Lots more queries here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Comment: Note that while this is a fine solution, behind the scenes it uses iteration.  Thats no problem for 10 objects, but can be slow if overused on larger collections, so be aware of it.

Comment: Actually, iterators are slow in cases where the time cost of iteration is more significant than the time cost of processing each value in the loop, *and* the collection is large (up in the hundreds). If that's the case though, you'd likely want to reconsider your choice of data structure to begin with: a sorted native array, a tree, or a dictionary of lists would fare better, as they'd be O(log N), O(log N) and O(1) for searching respectively -- as opposed to the O(N) you get with an unsorted ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 5):

No, `Contains` only looks for a specific value, not something matching a predicate. It also only finds *one* value rather than every matching value.

You can, however, use [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301979.aspx) from LINQ to Objects, assuming you're on .NET 3.5 or higher:

```
foreach (var item in list.Where(x => x.Age == 10))
{
    // Do something with item
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `Collection<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>`...you can use the LINQ to Object extension methods to make this simple (even though it will use iteration in the background):

```
var results = list.Where(m => m.age == 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, using `.Where(i => i.Age == 10)` would be the correct way to get the result stated in the question.  You would use `.Contains()` to check your collection for a specific instance of your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to do this but not `Contains`

```
 var foo = from bar in myCollection where bar.age == 10 select bar;
```